# Is it possible to write software for a keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, mouse, gaming

I just got a new Cooler Master Octane keyboard+mouse combo, but it doesn't come with any software, so I can't modify the keys, or change any function...is there a way to write some simple software for it? Thank you

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Microsoft Keyboard Layout Editor is a good tool for creating new layouts or making major changes to existing ones, and the results can be install on any other PC without needing supporting software. If you just want to remap a couple of keys, or perhaps swap/disable a modifier key (CTRL, SHIFT etc.) then MSKLC is overkill.

For more information kindly refer to this link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/goglobal/bb964665.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
Regards

Answer (score 0):

## Special Keys and AutoHotKey

If you are using Windows, you should use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com). It is an awesome programming language (simple, easy and practical) for create hotkeys! In your case what we can do is find the actual key code for the special keys on your keyboard (or just use normal keys) and give them specific functionality.

### Getting Started

- **Install** [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com)
- **Create** a *filename.ahk* file
- **Use** [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) to find the codes that correspond to your special keys

  - The code provided can help with this
- **Run** the file by right clicking it and opening with `AutoHotKey.exe`
- **Modify** the AHK code here to suit your needs once you have the key codes for your specific keys
- **Enjoy** the power of AutoHotKey!

### Code

This AHK file has the keyboard hook you need to find the codes for the special keys on your keyboard. It also has two example hotkeys (+ comments). The first is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SC159</kbd> and opens Google in your default browser (I don't know to which key `SC159` corresponds). The second is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> and it also opens Google in your default browser. Since I [really](https://github.com/NonlinearFruit/Ultimate) like AHK and this code needs a fun example, I also included <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> which googles the currently highlighted text (without changing your clipboard).

```ahk
#InstallKeybdHook

;Here is an example of a code for a special key
;This will open google.com
^SC159:: Run www.google.com

;Here is an example of a normal hotkey
;This will open google.com
^g:: Run www.google.com

;Insta-(G)oogle
+#g::
    old = %clipboard% 
    Sleep 10
    Send ^c
    Sleep 100
    data = %clipboard%
    clipboard = %old%
    search = http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%data%
    Run %search%
    Return
```

### Bonus

- You can open `Ahk2exe.ex`e to conver a `ahk` file to an `exe`

  - This will allow it to run on **any** Windows PC
- Placing the file in your startup folder will make it auto-start every time you log in
- When you modify your code, make sure to save it and reload the ahk script
- To stop a script, right click the ahk icon in the taskbar and click exit
- [Here](http://xahlee.info/mswin/autohotkey_examples.html) are some example AHK scripts

**[NOTE:** Some Special Keys on some keyboards won't be detectable by AHK **]**